# How can I find out the size of a swap partition?

Tags: linux, swap

What are the sizes of the following swap partitions?

```
root@pc:~# swapon -s -v
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda5                               partition       4192252 0       -1
/dev/sdc1                               partition       3156736 0       -2
/dev/sdb1                               partition       4194300 0       -3
```

What does size mean? Is it 4k blocks? Or 512byte blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you got 3 swap partitions.
to answer your question, you can type these commands:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda5
fdisk -l /dev/sdc1
fdisk -l /dev/sdb1
```

learn more about Linux swap [here](https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8208-all-about-linux-swap-space/)

Comment: In newer util-linux versions (at least 2.27.1), [`swapon`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/swapon.8.html) deprecated the `-s` flag in favor to the `--show` and is also able to tell the size in Bytes; ie: `swapon --show=NAME,SIZE --raw --bytes`

Answer (score 8):

The sizes are in kilobytes since `swapon -s` is equivalent to `cat /proc/swaps`.

If you want to see the combined swap space use `free`. It can sum and convert to, for example, megabytes: `free -m`.

Answer (score 2):

It is in kilobytes. 1,024 byte units.